# Trying to better understand time complexity - multiple operations of the same speed

Tags: runtime, big-o

When analyzing the time complexity of a function, do we account for multiple instances of operations with the same runtime? For example, let's say we have the function below:

```
my_fake_function(int v) {
   for(int i=0; i < v; i++;) { // O(V)
      someDatastructure.insert("test"); // insert() is O(log(n))
      someDatastructure.insert("test"); // insert() is O(log(n))
   }
}
```

So we know this function runs V times and that, for every iteration, a insert() is called twice. Given that insert has a hypothetical runtime of O(log(n)), would that make the overall runtime for the function `O(V*log(n))` or `O(V*2log(n))`? The insert() operation is running twice but I'm not entirely clear on if we show that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. Your function makes *2v* `insert` calls, thus making the overall time complexity *O(2 v log(n))*.

However, if you study the definition of the big-O notation, you will find that *O(2 v log(n))* is the same class of functions as *O(v log(n))*. As a rule, constant coefficients (if *> 0*) can be omitted: *O(c f(n)) = O(f(n))* for constant *c > 0*.

Thus, it is as correct to claim that your function runs in *O(2 v log(n))* time as it is to say it runs in *O(v log(n))* time. However, we tend to describe complexity classes by a
a simplified expression, so in practice you will see *O(v log (n))*.

I suggest you take some time to understand the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big-O notation, as it would have answered this question for you already. If the formal mathematical definition is not for you, there are also plenty of online sources that do a good job at explaining what it means in practical terms.